# How to get list of users in Personal Projects workspace using Asana API

Tags: asana

I get an empty user list whenever I request the list of users in my Personal Project workspace using the Asana API:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/MY-PERSONAL-PROJECTS-WORKSPACE-ID/users

According to the web app, I should get myself and my wife (cuz you know, she figured out how to get me to do things... ;)

Strangely when I request the list of all users in all workspaces, my wife does show up with my Personal Projects listed in her workspaces:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users?opt_fields=id,name,workspaces

Is this normal? How would I get myself and my wife to be listed for the Personal Projects workspace?

Thanks

Comment: In fact, just realized https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users?opt_fields=id,name,workspaces lists every user of everyone of my workspaces are being a member of my Personal Projects workspace. Is it just me or this makes no sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal Projects is kind of "special" - technically, there is only one Personal Projects workspace, and everyone is a member of it. That's why your wife shows up as a member of Personal Projects - she's in her own Personal Projects. We use different access control to keep people's Personal Projects separate. You'll find that if you make a request on behalf of your wife, her Personal Projects has the same ID as yours.

As a result, Personal Projects don't have "members" in the same way as normal workspaces. I know that's not very satisfying, but I hope it's at least better to have a definitive "it doesn't work that way" than just wondering why it doesn't :-/

Comment: "Personal Projects is kind of special" seems to be a frequent answer. Poor kid...  ;)